# How to get the info about the clicked point of interest?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

How do I get the data of the location (i.e. lat and lng) that is clicked? (See image below)

[image: GoogleMapsApp]

I have tried this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { ... };
```

But this event does *not* get fired when pressing on that restaurant icon (I used **The Sand** as example).

Comment: The event listener you just created is for the baloon on the map

Comment: @martynas What should I use else?

Comment: I am not sure - i am not very familiar with the API. Let me have a look in the documentation - i might come up with something.

Comment: @martynas I would highly appreciate that, I have searched myself too in the docs AND google but couldn't find it...

Comment: It's kind of marker with label which you "don't own": click event listener is already written for it (my assumption). And from docs for map click event: *This event is fired when the user clicks on the map (**but not when they click on a marker or infowindow**).*

Comment: @AntoJurković So I can't get any data from it? Can you post the URL? Thanks!

Comment: The icon you've clicked is a POI (technically a 'MapTypeStyleFeatureType') which you have little control over, other than being able to prevent them displaying.  See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeStyleFeatureType - this one is probably of type `poi.business`

Comment: @duncan So you're telling me that you're only able to show/hide 'em? No way to retrieve data about them?

Comment: URL: [map click event](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Map)

Comment: @Houssni unfortunately, yes. This is not (yet) supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it is a not-yet-supported feature.

These places are called **Points Of Interest (a.k.a. POI)** and a custom event cannot be assigned to it yet.